# Using 2D metaballs to draw an outline with a constant thickness

Tags: graphics, 2d, glsl, shader, geometry-surface

I'm apply the concept of metaballs to a game I'm making in order to show that the player has selected a few ships, like so http://prntscr.com/klgktf

However, my goal is to keep a constant thickness of this outline, and that's not what I'm getting with the current code.

I'm using a GLSL shader to do this, and I pass to the fragmentation shader a uniform array of positions for the ships (u_metaballs).

Vertex shader:

```
#version 120

void main() {
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
}
```

Fragmentation shader:

```
#version 120

uniform vec2 u_metaballs[128];

void main() {
    float intensity = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 128 && u_metaballs[i].x != 0; i++){
        float r = length(u_metaballs[i] - gl_FragCoord.xy);
        intensity += 1 / r;
    }

    gl_FragColor = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0);
    if(intensity > .2 && intensity < .21)
        gl_FragColor = vec4(.5, 1, .7, .2);
}
```

I've tried playing around with the intensity ranges, and even changing 1 / r to 10000 / (r ^ 4) which (although it makes no sense) helps a bit, though it does not fix the problem.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Constant thickness is probably not achievable with the fragment shader approach. You could extract the isoline on the CPU and pass that information as a line strip to the GPU. Or you can do an image-based thinning on the result of your fragment shader. Though, this is probably computationally heavier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after some more taught it is doable even in single pass ... you just compute the distance to nearest metaball and if less or equal to the boundary thickness render fragment otherwise discard it ... Here example (assuming single quad `<-1,+1>` is rendered covering whole screen):

**Vertex:**

```cpp
// Vertex
varying vec2 pos;       // fragment position in world space
void main()
    {
    pos=gl_Vertex.xy;
    gl_Position=ftransform();
    }
```

**Fragment:**

```cpp
// Fragment
#version 120
varying vec2 pos;

const float r=0.3;  // metabal radius
const float w=0.02; // border line thickness
uniform vec2 u_metaballs[5]=
    {
    vec2(-0.25,-0.25),
    vec2(+0.25,-0.25),
    vec2( 0.00,+0.05),
    vec2(+0.30,+0.35),
    vec2(-1000.1,-1000.1),  // end of metaballs
    };

void main()
    {
    int i;
    float d;
    // d = min distance to any metaball
    for (d=r+r+w+w,i=0;u_metaballs[i].x>-1000.0;i++)
     d=min(d,length(pos-u_metaballs[i].xy));
    // if outside range  ignore fragment
    if ((d<r)||(d>r+w)) discard;
    // otherwise render it
    gl_FragColor=vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
    }
```

**Preview:**

[image: preview]

Comment: Alright thanks! I'll try this and I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: From the preview it kind of defeats the purpose of using metaballs but for my purposes it's the same so I'll take this as a solution to my problem.

Comment: By the way, is there any performance impact of using discard in this situation instead of gl_FragColor = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0)?

Comment: @Tom I think discard should be faster or the same speed. The real difference is that by setting color to `vec4(0,0,0,0)` without blending you are clearing pixels to black ... so if you got any bacground gfx or already rendered stuff it will be overwritten by the black. By using discard its like transparency ... so you can easily combine this shader with other rendering stuff. On the other hand discard can not be optimized to be branchless so in case you encode some equation that mimics the `if` statement (like I did for the `d`) the branchless color setting might be faster.